# Javascript audio object onload event

Tags: javascript, audio

I'm triying to call a function when Javascript `audio()` object is loaded, but It doesn't work using `onload`.

```
myaud.onload = audioDone;
```

But it's working with the `image()` object. How can I make it working with `audio()` object ? 
**Thanks**

Answer (score 8, accepted):

An `<audio>` element has a specific set of events called [media events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Media_events), and `onload` is not one of them

You can check if the audio is loaded and can be played through with the `canplaythrough` event

```
myaud.addEventListener('canplaythrough', audioDone, false);
```